# Филология самостоятельно. Посоветуйте любые материалы

Tags: образование

Хочу изучать филологию самостоятельно, по многим причинам.
Есть ли хорошие сайты с записями лекций, учебники, "задачники"?
Хорошо бы список программ  — что надо знать?

Спрашиваю об учебниках сложного уровня. Учебник Розенталя кажется неинтересным. Например, в теме о корнях скак/скоч упоминается только о том что:
перед к пишется - а
перед ч пишется -о.

А о том сто есть исключение в виде форм глагола скакать - ни слова. (вскочу - вскачу, заскочу - заскачу.....) А мне хочется где-то потренироваться на сложном уровне.

Comment: Грамота.ру. Грамма.ру. См. также: [Розенталь, Д. Э.,Джанджакова Е.В., Кабанова Е.В. СПРАВОЧНИК ПО ПРАВОПИСАНИЮ, ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЮ, ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМУ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЮ. М.: ЧеРо,1999](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/21.htm)

Comment: [Полный академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина. Правила русской орфографии и Пунктуации](http://orthographia.ru/)   Там же увидите аналогичный справочник Розенталя.

Comment: См. Глазарий языка в Фейсбуке, В социальной сети ВКонтакте. А также в Ютубе.

Answer (score 1):

Александр, увы, Ваши нынешние познания на уровне начальной школы.

Смотрите:

Может (ЗАПЯТАЯ, вводное) в **И**нтернете ("**[Как писать слово Интернет?](http://gramota.ru/biblio/magazines/gramota/28_366)**") есть хорошие сайты с записями лекций, видео**-**лекциями (СЛИТНО). Учебники, "задачники"... Хорошо бы полный список программы - что я должен знать. Любые сайты, книги (ЗАПЯТАЯ, тире не обосновано), которыми вы сами пользуетесь.

Пожалуйста (ЗАПЯТАЯ, частица в значении вводного) не нужно материал**ОВ** для школьников. Интересует высшее (?).

> **ВИДЕО...** [от лат. videre - видеть] Первая часть сложных слов. Обозначает отнесённость чего-л. к воспроизведению изображения с
>   магнитного или иного носителя. *Видеоаппаратура, видеозал,
>   видеоинформация, видеосвязь, видеолекция.*

---

Можно выучиться на филолога, выучив наизусть все учебники. Розенталь, Мильчин...

Я выучилась на "редактора текста, филолога", проработав двенадцать лет в коррректорской (словаря не выпуская из рук), окончив Полиграфический институт, сделав (подготовив к печати) не один десяток книг, и продолжаю учиться по сей день, потому что выявляется потихонечку нехватка общекультурного образования (так, на днях я на этом сайте уверенно причислила написание "ефесский" к устаревшему пласту лексики, поправив на "э", а старшие товарищи меня поправили: в житиях святых уместнее именно начальное "е").

Вот Вам тема: **[Когда нужны буквенные наращения после цифр?](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/87-rubric-99)**. Если осилите на раз-два - дерзайте, получайте высшее без среднего.

Comment: Спасибо за полный ответ.